# Asp.Net MVC 4 clean URL load index.html from subdirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I've a ASP.NET MVC 4 Project and I have a subdirectory "test" in the root dir and it contains a index.html

I want wenn the clean URL is called that the index.html is returned

when I call

http://localhost:8080/

that I get the Content returned from my "test\index.html"

Comment: are you not using razor engine's .cshtml pages?

Comment: You are looking for routing, this article from MSDN shows you how to register a `default route` (what you are looking for): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @Aravind no I am using Angular 2

Comment: @squadwuschel in that case (with angular) this link may be more useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/24071300/3061857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RouteConfig` class in the `App_Start` sub-directory should be adjusted so that the default Controller is `Test`.  Place your 'test' directory within the `Views` directory and, if you haven't already, create a `TestController`.  `RouteConfig` should look like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what I am looking for I've added a ActionResult in my TestController which returns => { return new FilePathResult("~/test/index.html", "text/html"); }

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put your "test/index.html" as default document in IIS.

If you really want to do it programmatically you'll have to create an action to handle your request and map your default route to it.

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "StaticFile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Controller/Action:

```
public class StaticFileController : Controller
{
    // GET: StaticFile
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public FileContentResult Index()
    {
        string imageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Test/Index.html");
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);

        return File(bytes, "text/html");
    }
}
```